# Customer Portal user and queue handling

Tags: customer-portal, workflow, user

I had the amazing idea to create a class coupled with a Visualforce page, that allows a Customer Portal user to create cases.  It all works fine, except that the Portal User is unable to access the Queue sObject and is therefore unable to transfer the ownership of the case to the designated queue.

I've tried both to set the ownerId in the class code, that just bombs out with an error stating that the QueueSobject is unavailable.  I then tried a workflow rule that runs whenever the CP user creates a new case, this does not work either. And any triggers I run on the Case object fail for this user since CP users have no access to Queues at all.

How can this be handled?  If I create a Time Trigger as a reaction to the case insertion - as who will that time trigger run?  If it's still the CP User then that will also fail.

Comment: have you checked to make sure all the user who you want to use your tool have permission to your class?  those users' profiles will also need to be able to read, edit, and create any object you use to access/store data (the **Case** Standard Object for your instance).

Comment: Oh yes, the problem is not that the Case isn't created, it works fine.  But when I try to set the Case Owner via workflow it fails.  But I just had a good idea, just use a Site for it. Then all cases created will be created as the Site User but not the CP User and then all workflows should work.

Comment: I suggest getting everything to work for all the profiles that you desire your tool to work for **before** writing any sort of trigger code.  I try to use triggers as a last resort because they become unwieldy and difficult to maintain when used in excess

Comment: ah, it's getting it to populate from the Queue.  hmm